# Gradle: figure out a Maven dependency scope by using `Configuration` and its dependency set

Tags: java, maven, gradle, groovy, dependency-management

So I'd like given a Groovy [Configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html) and its [Dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/DependencySet.html) figure out the Maven dependency scope, of which there are [six](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

For some dependencies it is trivial, as `implementation` translates to Mavens `compile` neatly.

What to do about things like `errorpone`? This configuration has its own dependencies, but what is their Maven scope? Is there a way to tell programmatically? I'd like to avoid having a huge `Map<Configuration, String>` of configuration -> its maven scope.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually in Gradle we are free to create any configuration we want, like in the case of `errorpone` (whatever that means). Configurations are created from the build scripts, they can extend other configurations (inheriting all items contained in the other config), and in example, single items can be added/removed to a configuration, using the gradle build script. So there isn't a one-to-one relation with Maven scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle has a much richer model than the hardcoded scopes of Maven. Relationship to Maven scopes matters only when publishing a library to a Maven repository, using a `pom.xml` for the metadata.

I recommend reading [documentation around configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/managing_dependency_configurations.html) or watching the webinar on the topic of [dependency management fundamentals](https://gradle.com/blog/dependency-management-with-gradle-fundamentals-2/) (Note: I am co-presenter in this webinar)